# How to get intance of InvocationContext for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, java-ee-6, interceptor, powermockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a method taking the InvocationContext as parameter. More specifically here's the signature and essentials of the method.

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object autoLogMethodCall(final InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

    String className = context.getClass().getSimpleName();
    String packageName = context.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    String methodName = context.getMethod().getName();

    // Some logging stuff that is the target of actual testing
}
```

As you see, it is an interceptor method I intend to use for doing some basic logging for certain method calls.

Then I have unit test which I want to test that the logged messages will be properly formatted. But the problem is that that I can not create an instance of the **InvocationContext** to pass as a parameter for testing.

I have tried the following mocking.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class AutoLoggingTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testAutoLogger() {
        Logger log = new MyLogger(); // This is an implementation of org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger, which will hold the generated messages to check at the test
        InvocationContext mockContext = PowerMockito.mock(InvocationContext.class);
        Class clazz = AutoLoggingTest.class;
        // The row causing the error 'MissingMethodInvocation'
        PowerMockito.when(mockContext.getClass()).thenReturn(clazz);

try {
    InterceptingClass ic = new InterceptingClass();
    ic.setLogger(log);
    ic.autoLogMethodCall(mockContext);
    MyLogger myLogger = (MyLogger) ic.getLogger();
    assertEquals(2, myLogger.getMessages().size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Should not cause an exception in any case");
        }
    }
    // Check the actual messages based on the information given in mocked InvocationContext object
}
```

But it does not work.
    causes:

> Tests in error: 
>       AutoLoggingTest.testAutoLogger:25 » MissingMethodInvocation.
>       when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.).

Any advice on how to do the mocking properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required some thinking out of the box. Some mixed content with the mocked InvocationContext is needed. We can provide the testing class itself in the mocked InvocationContext object, thus I added and changed the following in the test class itself:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class AutoLoggingTest extends TestCase {

    // This method needs to be added here to provide it for mocked InvocationContext.
    public void methodForLoggingTesting() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testAutoLogger() {

        Logger log = new MyLogger();
        // Some renaming & refactoring after the initial stuff
        AutoLoggingUtility alu = new AutoLoggingUtilityImplForTesting();
        alu.setLogger(log);
        InvocationContext mockContext = PowerMockito.mock(InvocationContext.class);
        try {
            Method testMethod = this.getClass().getMethod("methodForLoggingTesting");
            PowerMockito.when(mockContext.getMethod()).thenReturn(testMethod);
            PowerMockito.when(mockContext.proceed()).thenReturn(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Should not throw an exception, InvocationContext mocking failed!");
        }
        try {
            alu.autoLogMethodCall(mockContext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Should not throw an exception, logging failed!");
        }
        MyLogger myLogger = (MyLogger) alu.getLogger();
        assertEquals(3, myLogger.getMessages().size());

        // More tests to check the actual logged content
    }
}
```

Also I realized I should provide the code for the 'MyLogger' as it wasn't quite trivial to implement for the test.

```
// Logger = org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
// ExtendedLoggerWrapper = org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.ExtendedLoggerWrapper
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
protected class MyLogger extends ExtendedLoggerWrapper implements Logger {
    private List<String> messages;

    public MyLogger() {
        super(null, null, null);
        this.clearMessages();
    }

    // The actual log calls need to get stored to store the messages + prevent from NullPointerExceptions
    @Override
    public void trace(String msg) {
        messages.add(msg);
    }

    // The actual log calls need to get stored to store the messages + prevent from NullPointerExceptions
    @Override
    public Object exit(Object obj) {
        messages.add("Exited with: " + obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public List<String> getMessages() {
        return this.messages;
    }

    public void clearMessages() {
        messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * You need to override all the method calls used to prevent NullPointerExceptions.
     *
     * @return <code>True</code> always, as required so in test.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And since there was some minor refactoring needed in the original Logging class, it now looks like this:

```
public abstract class AutoLoggingUtility {

    private static final String logEntryTemplate = "Call to: %1$s#%2$s";
    private static final String logExitTemplate = "'%1$s' call duration: %2$s ms";

    public AutoLoggingUtility() {

    }

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object autoLogMethodCall(final InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    // Note the methods Overridden in MyLogger
    if (this.getLogger().isTraceEnabled()) {
        String methodName = null;
        String className = null;
        try {
            Method method = context.getMethod();
            methodName = method.getName();
            // Contains package
            className = context.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // May not crash
                methodName = "?method?";
                className = "?class?";
            }
            Object[] args1 = { className, methodName };
            String logMsg = String.format(getLogentrytemplate(), args1);
            this.getLogger().trace(logMsg);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
            return this.getLogger().exit(context.proceed());
            } finally {
            Object[] args2 = { methodName, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime };
            logMsg = String.format(getLogexittemplate(), args2);
            this.getLogger().trace(logMsg);
        }
    } else {
        // mocked
        return context.proceed();
    }

    /**
     * Forces each extending class to provide their own logger.
     *
     * @return The logger of the extending class to direct the messages to correct logging context.
     */
    abstract Logger getLogger();
}
```

The '*AutoLoggingUtilityImplForTesting*' simply extends '*AutoLoggingUtility*' to hold instance of *MyLogger*.

Summarum:
The trick is to provide instance of the test classes method '*methodForLoggingTesting*' for the mocked object to return when the '*getMethod()*' is called. => No need to try to mock excess stuff.